# Hibernate Criteria: Ordenar lista pela maior data de um objeto filho

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

Como faço para criar um Criteria para listar um objeto ordenando pela maior data de um objeto filho. Nesse cenário:

**Domain:**

```
class Entity {
    List<Children> childrens;
}

class Children {
    Date date
}
```

**Algo tipo isso em SQL:**

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    entity
INNER JOIN 
    children c1 ON c1.entity_id = entity.id
WHERE 
    c1.date = 
        (SELECT MAX(c2.date) FROM children c2 WHERE c2.entity_id = c1.entity_id) 
ORDER BY 
    c1.date DESC
```

Comment: você tá usando Jdbc pura, hibernate, springboot ou o que?

Comment: Hibernate Criteria (https://www.devmedia.com.br/hibernate-api-criteria-realizando-consultas/29627)